# Can I use a 700V transistor with a 12V collector and base?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, hobbyist

Please forgive any misunderstandings, as I am not an expert on electrical components.

I am trying to build the following circuit:

[image: Example circuit with an NPN transistor and two 12v power sources]

I need to be able to run 1.5A through the transistor. Can I use a 700V rated transistor to do this such as the one with the [specifications here?](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2281319.pdf)

Comment: 12 V on the collector is fine. 12 V on the base is absolutely not.

Comment: You must have a base resistor.

Comment: @Hearth I would just need to add a resistor right? What would I need to decrease the base voltage to in order to be safe here?

Comment: Yes, a resistor would solve the problem.

Comment: @winny

Would this work then: https://i.imgur.com/W0TpalE.png

Comment: Not with the voltmeter there. Why are you hooking up a voltmeter like that?

Comment: Fix your circuit; show the actual supply voltages and show the proper transistor name. There is absolutely no substitute for accuracy in the schematic. The schematic is king and, transient words that may modify it, are the devil set to trip you up. The data sheet link implies one of two transistors <-- clarity please.

Comment: https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/how-transistors-work/

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use that particular transistor? Is it because you have some already? Do you have an application for this or are you just experimenting? If we know what you're trying to do and why we can provide better answers.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, I think I have fixed it here: https://i.imgur.com/SWDJBeW.png

Comment: @GodJihyo I mainly am using it because I couldn't find a transistor with a 15v 1.5A rating that I could buy individually. The idea is to replicate an ignition switch-powered device in a car, where the device needs to be connected directly to the battery, but is only switched on when the car has been started. I have fixed the diagram to better reflect this with the device added to the circuit here: https://i.imgur.com/SWDJBeW.png

Comment: @Ant The load doesn't go in the emitter leg. It goes in the collector leg. If you *must* have one end of the load tied to the chassis/ground/minus side of things (say, the device is screwed into the chassis and relies upon the chassis as its negative rail), then you need a PNP BJT (D45H11, for example) as the switch to switch the high side. And the load ***still*** goes onto the collector. Does the switch itself have to source from 12 V? Or can one end be tied to ground, instead? How much latitude do you have here?

Comment: @jonk I think I see, is this what you mean? https://i.imgur.com/j2SKFRQ.png or this? 
https://i.imgur.com/iFul5aa.png

Comment: Are you just trying to turn the light on and off? If so it would be much better to use a MOSFET.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the most prominent problem is that you are talking about \$1.5\:\text{A}\$ into the load. For a BJT switch, the usual assumption for \$\beta\$ when saturated is \$\beta=10\$ or maybe as much as \$\beta=20\$.

If you look at the [D45H11](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/d44h-d.pdf) device (commonly available), you'll see that they use \$\beta=10\$ for their curves involving switching. So you should probably stay with that.

This means your base current will be about \$150\:\text{mA}\$. And that's a ***lot***. This is about where you have to make a decision about using BJTs or MOSFETs. \$150\:\text{mA}\$ at anything near \$12\:\text{V}\$ means almost \$2\:\text{W}\$ wasted on just the drive requirement. A MOSFET doesn't require that waste for drive purposes -- especially if this isn't being switched ON and OFF often. So this is an important departure point -- BJT or MOSFET?

If this whole thing is a car battery, then the BJT is probably fine. Sure, there's a LOT of wasted power. But it's not a lot compared to what the car battery can support. And BJTs are simple and readily available. (And cheaper, as a rule.)

But a wasted \$2\:\text{W}\$ is a wasted \$2\:\text{W}\$. And may require more expensive parts and complicate dissipation considerations. So this gets back to the question of using a MOSFET, once again. The MOSFET switch is likely to dissipate about the same as the BJT switch. But the drive circuit for the MOSFET will be different and will be about \$2\:\text{W}\$ less than the BJT circuit requires.

It's possible that the D45H11 can get by on \$\beta=20\$ and therefore only require \$1\:\text{W}\$ of additionally wasted power. But you need to figure out which way to go based upon your own considerations about availability, cost, and wasted power.

For now, let's stick with the BJT-switch. That's where your question started. And that's where I'll go. I also take it that you don't care how the load and switch are wired. So that makes things easier, as well.

Let's say we use the PNP D45H11 and assume \$\beta=15\$ for switching purposes. Then the following circuit should be okay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9KQGH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_1\$ will need to be about \$2\:\text{W}\$ or better. But it should be fine providing the necessary base current to switch \$Q_1\$. If, in testing, you aren't getting quite what you expected for the load, feel free to change \$R_1\$ to \$100\:\Omega\$ (same wattage.) Should work fine, then.

Note that the load is in the collector leg, as I'd mentioned earlier in comments.

(If you were controlling this from an MCU and not a switch, then the design would need to be substantially modified.)

The other option might be to use an N-FET and an entirely different arrangement. The [IRFZ44NPbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) might be a fine choice for an N-FET. Similarly, so might be an [IRFP150](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91203/91203.pdf). The load would be tied to \$+12\:\text{V}\$ instead of ground and the switch arrangement would be a little different, too. But those may be fine options, depending on cost and availability to you.

Answer (score 0):

DC current gain of that transistor is about 8, so for 1 amp into the 8 ohm load, you would need about 125 mA base drive current, or a resistor with a value of about (12-9)/.125 = 24 ohms. But current gain can vary, so you may get more current, although it will be limited to about 10 volts and 1.25 amps.

If the load must be connected to ground, you might want to use Darlington connected transistors as an emitter follower, with a voltage divider to provide the desired voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiBKDf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: An emitter follower is not how you want to do this. In fact, a darlington arrangement will be even worse here. If the load has to be connected to ground, use PNP transistors.

Comment: I had assumed that the OP wanted to apply 1 amp through the 8 ohm load, which would be 8 volts, and not the nearly 1.5 A that would be the case if 12 V was applied.

Comment: @PStechPaul It seems more likely to me that the OP mistyped that current value and that the device is really a 12 V device. The OP does later write "1.5A rating" in comments, which may be suggestive of either (1) confusion, or (2) mistyped in Q but wrote better in comments. I wouldn't want to bet on an 8 V load, myself.

Comment: @jonk you are correct in that I mistyped the Q. The device is 12v and the load is 1.5A.

Comment: @Ant Noted. Also, if you take a moment and tell me about the switch (does one end need to be tied to ground) and the load (does one end need to be tied to +12) -- or if either can be connected either way -- then I may write. Otherwise, without clear details for each, I'm still a little in the dark.

Comment: @jonk Either can be connected either way. There aren't any hard requirements.